# Change the array and return a new one

Tags: javascript

I have an array with objects. I filtered the array and returned the values that correspond with a condition. After that i created a new array what contains data from first. This array contains a value `a` which should overrides the first array.

```js
const arr = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    name: 'one'
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 7,
    name: 'two'

  }
]

const b = [1, 2]
const res = arr.filter(i => b.includes(i.b))
const newArr = {
  ...res,
  a: 'newdata'
}

console.log(newArr)
```

In console i got:

```js
{
  "0": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "name": "one"
  },
  "a": "newdata"
}
```

But the expected output is:

```js
  {
  "a": "newdata"
  "b": 2,
  "name": "one"
  },
```

Why i get this and how to get the expected result?

Comment: `find` instead of `filter`? The latter returns an array, seems you just want a single element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you filter the values you're interested in, you could use [`Array.map(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to go through all the items and change their `a` property, here is an example:

```js
const arr = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    name: 'one'
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 7,
    name: 'two'

  }
]

const b = [1, 2]
const res = arr.filter(i => b.includes(i.b)).map(i => ({...i, a: 'newdata'}));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply spread an array and you get the indices from the array/object as key and the item/object as value.

Instead, you could take a function for a new object with additional key/value and map the filtered result by using the function.

```js
const
    arr = [{ a: 1, b: 2, name: 'one' }, { a: 1, b: 7, name: 'two' }],
    b = [1, 2, 7],
    res = arr.filter(i => b.includes(i.b)),
    newObject = o => ({ ...o, a: 'newdata' }),
    newArr = res.map(newObject);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: _"**Why i get this** and how to get the expected result?"_

Comment: @Nina Scholdz, i need filter, because i could have multiple values, but find() return just one. What if `const b = [1,2,7]` not `const b = [1,2,]`

Comment: @AskMen, what is the wanted result in this case? please add this to the question. even if you unwrap the array, the last property wins.